# Finding the remainder of a Taylor Series

Tags: calculus

I had to find the nth Taylor polynomial for sin(x) and I now have to show that the remainder of sin(x) goes to 0.

I found the Taylor polynomial to be $\sum_{k=0}^n   \frac{(-1^{k+1})}{(2k+1)!}(x^{2k+1})$

The formula for finding the remainder is $R_nx=\frac{f^{n+1}(z)}{(n+1)!}(x-a)^{n+1}$. How do I use this formaula to show that the remainder of sin(x) goes to 0?

Comment: $f^{n+1}(z)$ is bounded, so all you need to do is show that $\frac{(x-a)^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}$ goes to $0$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$

Comment: and we know it's bounded since sin oscillates between -1 and 1? And for remainders, is it always as n--> infinity?

Comment: Yes, it is bounded because it is $\pm \sin(z)$ or $\pm \cos(z)$ for, I assume, real z. And yes, as you make better and better approximations (i.e. higher $n$) the remainder should get smaller, and become 0 in the limit.